# Mavericks system tool gets wrong notifications

Tags: macos, notifications

Mavericks has this system tool – I think it's called Notification Center from suggested related questions but I'm still with Lion – which shows notifications from many applications. It also shows Facebook notifications. Trouble is, it somehow logged in to MY Facebook account - on my DAD's computer. How do I tell it to log on to dad's user?

Comment: Just log out of your facebook on your dads computer. If you want you can even delete the facebook account (yours) in sys pref internet accounts, since you wont be using it there anymore.

Comment: In fact, we tried that, and of three browsers one logged to dad's account by itself and the others required login credentials, so that's not enough. I'll try removig it. I'm wondering how it got there though. Does it get there auto every time I log in?

Comment: Nope, it only gets activated when you log in, but if you forget to log out it will stay logged in even if you are no longer on the Facebook site. So make sure you log out of all 3 web browsers, sine they have the tendency to keep the log in credentials.

Comment: How exactly am I supposed to "make sure I log out" if one browser logs in to the correct account by itself and the others don't log in at all? I mean, what sense does it make to log in and back out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Preferences** -> **Internet Accounts** - delete Your Facebook account and add Your Dads Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to log in and the browser fills in the user and passowrd then that is your problem #1

1- Go to the key chain and delete all "your" Facebook accounts there on your dads computer. Be careful not to delete your dads accounts, that might result in a "you are grounded" for a Month penalty.

2- Disable the Keep me logged in in Facebook web page - Browser.

[image: facebook]

3- In case you have the Facebook set up in sys pref Internet Accounts - delete it.